# ValueError: Argument must be a dense tensor - Python and TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm extracting some portions of my code that might be relevant to the issue I'm having:

```
from PIL import Image
import tensorflow as tf

data = Image.open('1-enhanced.png')
...
...
raw_data = data
raw_img = raw_data
```

I'm getting the following long message which I'm not sure how to analyze (do you have any idea on what's going on here):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py", line 490, in apply_op
    preferred_dtype=default_dtype)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 669, in convert_to_tensor
    ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\constant_op.py", line 176, in _constant_tensor_conversion_function
    return constant(v, dtype=dtype, name=name)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\constant_op.py", line 165, in constant
    tensor_util.make_tensor_proto(value, dtype=dtype, shape=shape, verify_shape=verify_shape))
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\tensor_util.py", line 376, in make_tensor_proto
    _GetDenseDimensions(values)))
ValueError: Argument must be a dense tensor: <PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile image mode=L size=150x150 at 0x1E07D3C0AC8> - got shape [150, 150], but wanted [].

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "conv_visuals.py", line 54, in <module>
    x = tf.reshape(raw_data, shape=[-1,150,150,1])
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_array_ops.py", line 2448, in reshape
    name=name)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py", line 503, in apply_op
    as_ref=input_arg.is_ref).dtype.name
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 669, in convert_to_tensor
    ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\constant_op.py", line 176, in _constant_tensor_conversion_function
    return constant(v, dtype=dtype, name=name)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\constant_op.py", line 165, in constant
    tensor_util.make_tensor_proto(value, dtype=dtype, shape=shape, verify_shape=verify_shape))
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\tensor_util.py", line 376, in make_tensor_proto
    _GetDenseDimensions(values)))
ValueError: Argument must be a dense tensor: <PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile image mode=L size=150x150 at 0x1E07D3C0AC8> - got shape [150, 150], but wanted [].
```

Thanks.

Comment: Just a guess: Convert it to a numpy array: `numpy.asarray(Image.open('1-enhanced.png').convert('L'))`. Then try working it out?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment. Yes, I think that removed the error. I'm having another error though, but seems not related to this one.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just posting the comment since it seems to have resolved the issue:

Try converting it to a numpy array:

```
numpy.asarray(Image.open('1-enhanced.png').convert('L'))
```